# Azure Data Factory: map reduce activity fails when Linked Service configured with Service Principal to access Storage Account

Tags: azure, mapreduce, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, service-principal

We have an issue configuring the MapReduce activity in ADF.

If we use Linked Service with Service Principal as an Authentication method, it causes the following issue: `Activity Selector failed: The storage connection string is invalid`.

1. The Linked Service's test connection is successful.
2. MapReduce activity allows browsing the storage.
3. The Service Principal has enough rights assigned in Storage Account's resource group: "Storage Blob Data Owner"

When Linked Service configured with Account Key - everything works correctly.